# Neo4j - problem installing neo4j-graph-algorithms plugin

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am running neo4j on an ec2 machine and I want to run some graph algorithms. The problem is that some of the algorithms I want to use are not installed properly and I am getting this error :  `There is no procedure with the name xxxx registered for this database instance`.

By executing `CALL apoc.help('algo')` I only get 17 procedures and the procedures I want to use are not listed. Some of the procedures not listed are `apoc.algo.betweenness`, `apoc.algo.closeness` and `algo.pagerank.stream`

**neo4j version** : neo4j 3.5.14, 
**apoc-version** : [3.5.0.8](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.5.0.8/apoc-3.5.0.8-all.jar),
**neo4j-graph-algorithms-version** : [3.5.14](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/com.neo4j.graphalgorithms.dist/neo4j-graph-algorithms-3.5.14.0-standalone.zip)

I have also added this to my neo4j config file

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.*,apoc.algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*,apoc.algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=algo.*
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in neo4j logs I found out that I had some warnings!

So I changed some lines on my neo4j conf file

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.*,apoc.algo.*, algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*,apoc.algo.*, algo.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Some algorithms were moved from the APOC library to the [algo](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/) library, and improved along the way.

Here is the [documentation on the new `algo.betweenness`](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/betweenness-centrality) family of procedures.